# dimple.js: Tool-tip placement in a chart of a nested svg element

Tags: d3.js, svg, dimple.js

I am trying to modify [Bullet Charts example](http://dimplejs.org/advanced_examples_viewer.html?id=advanced_bullet) of `dimple.js` with each bullet chart being in a child-svg of the parent-svg. Purpose of having individual svg for each bullet chart is to make their management (show/hide/remove) easier. Also, this makes the recursive definition of a chart complete - That is, a chart is contained by an svg.

The [fiddle for the modified version is here...](http://jsfiddle.net/q0t5wLzq/2/).

As you can see, from 2nd chart onwards, on mouse hover, tool tips go out of place!!!  Please note that, for child-svg, I've set the style `overflow: visible` without which tool-tips were not visible at all.

Want to know if I am missing anything in handling the attributes of child-svg elements or is it a bug in dimple.js. Also, please let me know if you know of any workaround.

Thanks.

Comment: If I create individual svg elements as children of `#chartContainer` div element, then tool-tips get placed correctly. See the fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/q0t5wLzq/3/

Answer (score 0):

One of the first questions I have is why do you want child svg elements?  What are you trying to accomplish?
The only difference I see in your code and the example is the height / width swap at the top and the sub svg + bounds.

Keep in mind that the origin changes with each sub-svg. This might be why you are having trouble with the tool-tips.  Maybe you have that worked into your add-bullet calls.

I think nagu has the right approach here if you really want separate svg elements.

Comment: I have updated the question with the purpose of having child svg elements.